# Processing: Trying to animate the drawing of lines without draw function

Tags: java, animation, twitter, processing, draw

I'm trying to write a program that is under 140 characters(Twitter Char Limit). The program displays the final output I want but I don't understand why it's not showing the animation as it creates it. I thought it was because I don't have a draw function but I don't see why that matters if the drawing is all done within a For loop, anyways the draw function didn't help. I've tried bringing the framerate way down but yet for some reason it's only giving me a static final output. Any help is much appreciated.

```
int j=600, i=j/3;
size(j, j);
smooth();
translate(j/2, j/2);
for (i=1; i<12500; ) {
  fill(i%j, i%j);
  rotate(j%i*5);
  line(i++%j, i++%j, i+++j, int(i/99)%99);
}
```

Comment: and what does the PDE say when you run this? Also, if your `i` type is "int", then arithmetic operations with others ints stay ints (5 / 2 is the `int` 2, for instance, not a `float` or `double` 2.5), you don't need to do an `int(i/99)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing uses double buffering, which means that when you draw "to the screen", you're actually drawing to an off-screen buffer. Since your code is not in the draw() function, this happens before the frame is even visible. Then when the frame becomes visible, it takes the entire off-screen buffer, and draws the whole thing to the screen.

That's why you only see the end result of the drawing. If you want to display an animation, you'll have to use the draw() function and timing of some kind (the millis() method, for example).